# jQuery Draggable Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a draggable object to to a simple html page.

IE gives: Object doesn't support this property or method

FF gives: jQuery(".dragthis").draggable is not a function

Using latest jquery unpacked.
Here is the code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery(".dragthis").draggable();
                jQuery(".drophere").droppable();

            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .dragthis {
            }
            .drophere {
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="dragthis">dragthis</div>
        <div class="drophere">drophere</div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include the [jQuery UI library](http://ui.jquery.com/).